# $\int \frac{1}{(x+2)^{1/3}(x-1)^{2/3}}dx$

Tags: integration

How can I do the following integral?

$\int \frac{1}{(x+2)^{1/3}(x-1)^{2/3}}dx$

---

I have tried a lot of methods but I don't know how to do it

Comment: what methods have you tried? Have you tried by-parts?

Comment: According to Wolfram, that integral yields a hypergeometric function.

Comment: but how can I do it?

Comment: Not even Wolfie’s step-by-step solution feature on Pro (For Students) could tell me how to do it. Good luck, lol

Comment: Setting $u=x-1$ followed by $u=3t$ leads to a standard form of the beta function, although without integral bounds, you cannot go much further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this for you, though it acquires many steps of substitution and doing partial fractions. There may be some mistakes. Let me know if you have any questions or have found any typos or mistakes. I skip some algebra. You can complete on your own.

First, substitute $u=(x-1)^{1/3}$, $*=3\int\frac{1}{{u^3+3}^{1/3}}du$.

Second, substitute $v=\frac{{u^3+3}^{1/3}}{u}$ and apply partial fraction, $*=-\int\frac{v}{(v-1)(v^2+v+1)}dv=\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{1}{v-1}dv-\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{v-1}{v^2+v+1}dv$. The first integral is $\ln(v-1)$, and the second one, is $\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2v+1}{v^2+v+1}dv-\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{1}{v^2+v+1}dv$.

The first integral is $\ln(v^2+v+1)$, and for the second one, complete squares on the denominator and substitute $w=\frac{2v+1}{\sqrt{3}}$, get $=\frac{2\arctan(w)}{\sqrt{3}}$.

The trick is now over, and substitute every dummy variable back, and by some algebra, the answer is

$=\frac{\ln\big(\frac{(x+2)^{2/3}}{(x-1)^{2/3}}+\frac{(x+2)^{1/3}}{(x-1)^{1/3}}+1\big)}{2}-\sqrt{3}\arctan\big(\frac{\frac{2(x+2)^{1/3}}{(x-1)^{1/3}}+1}{\sqrt{3}}\big)-\ln(\frac{(x+2)^{1/3}}{(x-1)^{1/3}}-1)$.

If you find this helpful, please vote.

Comment: If you take $\ln|v-1|$ you can cover $x<1$ and $x>1$ with two constants $C_1,\ C_2$ for each interval with the remaining unchanged. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5tbwzky0fn

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> $u=\sqrt[3]{x-1} \implies \dfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} = \dfrac{1}{3\left(x-1\right)^\frac{2}{3}} \text{, then express everything in terms of $u$}$

Still will be quite a lot of work, but this works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try Beta function

let $u=\frac{x+2}{3}$ then
$$
\int u^{-1/3} (1-u) ^{-2/3} (-1)^{-2/3} \rm{dx} 
= (-1)^{-2/3} B(2/3, 1/3)
$$

Mind you that it is valid for $0<u<1$